# How to login sharepoint site using custom login page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have some users in my SharePoint site.I have a custom login page.I want to login to the site using the credentials i am giving in this page.How can i do it programmatically?I have added my active directory users to my site already.

Comment: If you are using Active Directory authentication, why you need custom login page ?

Comment: i have a login button in my anonymous page.On clicking the button a custom login page will come.

Comment: So you are using Forms authentication or Active Directory Authentication ?